# ASP.Net Identity built in functions with custom tables in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, authorize-attribute

I am using ASP.Net Core Web Api 2 on .Net 2.1 Framework
I have custom AppUsers and AppRoles tables, linked with bridge table AppUserRoles

My main problem is that I want to use `[Authorize(Roles = "UserRole")]` 
As User.Identity is working fine and I am getting user Id from `User.Identity.Name` I thought there was some way to set roles and check them before controller request, or to use `User.IsInRole("UserRole")` for checking inside controller.

Is it possible to rebuild or overload `.IsInRole("UserRole")` function or `[Authorize(Roles = "UserRole")]` attribute background function somehow, so I could write my own logic to check user permissions? Or to set my tables as default tables to use, so it could work on self logic. 
For my task, speed matters as much as security.

I am open to suggestions, if there is some other way, but my point also is to get better understanding in those functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to override Authorize or IsInRole. Just add the roles as claim to the User.Identity. You can use middleware to do the claims transformation.

As an example I suggest you take a look at the [PolicyServer](https://leastprivilege.com/2018/01/17/announcing-policyserver/). It has the same approach. The [free OSS version](https://policyserver.io/) adds claims in the middleware.

```
/// Add the policy server claims transformation middleware to the pipeline.
/// This middleware will turn application roles and permissions into claims
/// and add them to the current user
public static IApplicationBuilder UsePolicyServerClaims(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    return app.UseMiddleware<PolicyServerClaimsMiddleware>();
}
```

Where PolicyServerClaimsMiddleware is:

```
public class PolicyServerClaimsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PolicyServerClaimsMiddleware"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="next">The next.</param>
    public PolicyServerClaimsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoke
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <param name="client">The client.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IPolicyServerRuntimeClient client)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var policy = await client.EvaluateAsync(context.User);

            var roleClaims = policy.Roles.Select(x => new Claim("role", x));
            var permissionClaims = policy.Permissions.Select(x => new Claim("permission", x));

            var id = new ClaimsIdentity("PolicyServerMiddleware", "name", "role");
            id.AddClaims(roleClaims);
            id.AddClaims(permissionClaims);

            context.User.AddIdentity(id);
        }
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

And from startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddMvcCore(options =>
    {
        // workaround: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7809
        options.AllowCombiningAuthorizeFilters = false;
    })
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddAuthorization();

    // This is not relevant for you, but just to show how policyserver is implemented.
    // The bottom line is that you can implement this anyway you like.

    // this sets up the PolicyServer client library and policy
    // provider - configuration is loaded from appsettings.json
    services.AddPolicyServerClient(Configuration.GetSection("Policy"))
        .AddAuthorizationPermissionPolicies();

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();

    // add this middleware to make roles and permissions available as claims
    // this is mainly useful for using the classic [Authorize(Roles="foo")] and IsInRole functionality
    // this is not needed if you use the client library directly or the new policy-based authorization framework in ASP.NET Core
    app.UsePolicyServerClaims();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The example reads the configuration from file, which may be an option for you as well. But you can also implement a store and add some caching.

If you want to add some authorization logic then I suggest you create some policies and authorization handlers. Just make sure that you use the middleware at the right place.

---

An alternative is to use your own filter / attribute:

```
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

public class CustomPolicyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private int _number;

    public CustomPolicyAttribute(int number)
    {
        _number = number;
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var service = (IAuthorizationService)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IAuthorizationService));

        var requirement = new CustomRequirement
        {
            Number = _number
        };
        var result = await service.AuthorizeAsync(context.HttpContext.User, null, requirement);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
    }
}
```

You can use this in a couple of ways. Use as attribute (the Authorize equivalent):

```
[CustomPolicy(1)]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething()
{

}
```

Or validate manually (the IsInRole equivalent):

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;

    public MyController(IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
    {
        _authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(int number)
    {
        var requirement = new CustomRequirement
        {
            Number = number
        };
        var result = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, null, requirement);
        if (!result.Succeeded) return Forbid();

        return View("success");
    }
}
```

You will need an AuthorizationHandler to evaluate the requirement:

```
public class CustomRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CustomRequirement>
{
    // Use dependency injection to include services you need.
    public CustomRequirementHandler ()
    {
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CustomRequirement requirement)
    {
        // Add your advanced check here.
        if (requirement.Number > 0)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }
}
```

And register that in the startup:

```
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomRequirementHandler>();
```

In the handler you can add your own logic. In that case you won't have to add policies and you don't have to add authorization as claims.

Comment: I've got the point, I will try to implement that now, but before I start, is there any other "pure" way except going through claims?

If no, is there a way to use claims to check before controller request loads with annotation `Authorize`?

Comment: Thank you for fluent answer.
I will try to implement the logic now.
If I get any problem with that, I will update the post.
Cheers man!

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that there is also official documentation about this available: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x