# Storing multiple user values in identity cookie upon login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity

I have a piece of code upon user login like following:

```
 ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, model.Username));
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
var roles = user.UserRoles.ToList();
foreach (var item in roles)
{
 claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item.Roles.RoleName));
}
identity.AddClaims(claims);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserId.ToString()));
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true, ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(8) }, identity);
```

So once this piece of code is executed I can access user roles and user ID in other controllers like following:

```
User.Identity.Name // => getting user id of current logged user
```

And also:

```
   User.IsInRole("Regular"); // => getting user role in system
```

Now I have a need for more variables that would be stored in cookies upon user login like:

```
    // User theme => // I have multiple CSS files relating to different styles of page and I'd need to store this information in Identity as well.
// User preferences => multiple preferences as well
```

So that at the end of everything I can access that kind of information like this:

```
 User.Identity... // user theme
 User.Identity... // user preferences
```

How can I do this ?

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at PolicyServer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290721/asp-net-identity-built-in-functions-with-custom-tables-in-asp-net-core/52303393#52303393

Comment: Why don't you create your own claim and use same way?