# Maximum number of claims

Tags: asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

I have an asp.net core web app and I am using the built-in authorization system from Microsoft.

I have a number of areas, controllers and actions; every area, controller and action has its own separate claim.

I am running into a problem in that the webapp just crashes after a user logs in (no errors in output window). I am guessing this has to do with a maximum somewhere but I am not sure.

Is it ok to use 200+ claims?

The documents / tutorials I found are not clear about this.

Comment: 200+ claims is way too much. Please read this article: https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Good explanation.
Sadly I will have some restructuring to do now =)

I still think Microsoft is not very clear about this using of claims ..

Comment: I slept a night over the given answer and I altered my opinion. The link talks about identity server but I am not using Identity server, I am using ASP.NET Core Identity with tables AspNetUserClaims and AspNetRoleClaims. 

Why have Role Claims then ? I agree with the link author about authorization  "Microsoft services and frameworks kind of push you into that direction" and what would be the problem with using 200+ claims in my own WebApp ? 

In the tables I only manage the users of my web app system. It feels dumb to build my own authorization solution if there is a build in solution.

Comment: Seems to me that you are already hitting limits. What if you need an additional 100 claims? This is a strong indication that your design needs to change. Also it seems that roles are about to be removed in favor of claims: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813. And for authorization there are other more sophisticated options: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.1 Role-based authorization is just one of them.

Comment: I really don't know how AspNetRoleClaims are useful. I've never needed them. Or roles in general. The only reason to put everything into claims is to prevent an additional call to the database. But in the meantime you are taking additional bandwidth and hitting limits. Also this is 'old' information. A snapshot at the moment of login. Changes become effective only after the user logs in again. When you take the claims you really need (like sub or id) and use that to read the permissions from the database, you'll always have real-time information.

Comment: I agree with you. Sadly I will have to alter my approach. The 200+ was also a bit of a test because I wanted to know if I would run into problems. 
I am a bit disappointed because my solution was simple and elegant and worked great. I also still wonder what Microsoft had in mind when they designed it. claims to store a birth date or a drivers licence number, really ? Bedankt voor je uitgebreide antwoorden =)

Comment: There is another option that you may want to explore, the [PolicyServer](https://leastprivilege.com/2018/01/17/announcing-policyserver/). The OSS version is not a server but local middleware. In my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290721/asp-net-identity-built-in-functions-with-custom-tables-in-asp-net-core/52303393#52303393) I've added some information. It adds claims to the Identity using middleware. The sample uses a json file, but you can replace this with any store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruud answered the question. https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/ look in the comments above.

The link states claims or not meant for use in complex authorization.

I ended up building my own autorization system.