# Should permissions and roles be injected in token when using IdentityServer4 and ASP.NET Core identity

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, asp.net-core-identity

So, I'm spinning in circles at the moment. I have IdentityServer4 setup with ASP.NET Core identity and I need a way to handle roles and permissions so I can filter out who of the employees in my system has the permission to access the endpoint. So here where the dilemma comes.

1. Should I just inject all permissions and roles into access token. I see a lot of developers to that but as I recall Brock Allen and Dominick Baier mentioned in [this talk(at the time I've copied video)](https://youtu.be/-a7JbXL0hq0?t=386) that that is not a great idea because what if you have multiple Apis (which I don't at the moment but might in the future) that require different set of permissions (obviously you could inject the permissions and roles by the client_id that requests the authorization but idk is that the best idea).
   But on the other side Auth0 has RBAC implementation and they inject those into token.
2. Is it an option to have `UserManager` and `RoleManager` in my WebApi and have connection string to the IdentityServer database (I attached my basic flow and basic architecture in the picture below)? In this case I would have a query on the database on each request, but hey, SQL Server is fast :).
3. To have exposed endpoints on IdentityServer Api that would manage employee's roles and permissions (I dislike this idea the most but I just wanted to put it out there)

Is any of these approaches good or the best one is somewhere in the middle (or there isn't the best one)?

[image: My rudimentary architecture]

Comment: To [quote Dominick](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/#comment-133246): _IdentityServer is an authentication system_ and _PolicyServer is a generic multi-tenanted app roles/permission management system._. This suggests that IdentityServer isn't the best place to implement _user authorization_ but instead use an implementation of the [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/), which can be local (e.g. a json settings file) or external, but always related to the business logic. Please take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52079466/#52100609).

Comment: Yah this is basically coming back somewhere near my option #2 which I'm actually leaning forward to. I've looked at PolicyServer but we are not that big organization that we can afford it, but definitely we can take some ideas :). This comment is really useful.

Comment: You can use the open source version to start with. It's free and does in essence nothing more than adding claims through middleware, as I've tried to explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52303393/4864425). Please note that the 'authorization' context differs from the 'Authentication' context. UserManager and RoleManager are not sufficient because you need an additional discriminator. WHO is allowed to do WHAT WHERE and WHEN? You can use scopes to pinpoint WHERE (a scope defines a part of the functionality and is shared by client and resource) and WHEN as described with business rules.

Comment: At the moment I don't need WHERE but I might but I see your point. Your comments were most helpful. This is actually an opinioned solution to my problem :).
And one more thing if I may ask. How would you approach to the issue of one endpoint where if a user creates request from SPA app it needs to check users' permissions but if another service creates request to it (Client credentials) it does not require any roles and permissions and is allowed to proceed by just being authirized.

Comment: Use scopes. With a user based request the user allows the client to request data that is owned by the user. Client requests without user are often similar to batch jobs. This is different functionality so it's likely you can't use the same controller methods. Within the Api create seperate controllers decorated with scope based authorization, e.g. _ClientScope_ for the client controller. In startup add a policy based on the scope: `services.AddAuthorization(o => o.AddPolicy("ClientScope", p => p.RequireScope("ClientScope"));`. Now the controller is only accessable for clients with that scope.

Answer (score 2):

Roles and permissions tend to be application specific and can be a lot more difficult to manage at the authorization server.

I find that API claims caching is a better solution in most cases - since it separates concerns very cleanly.

See these resources of mine for more info;

- [Claims Caching Write Up](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/)
- [Sample Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts)

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 main approches to store permissions as general in access token:
claim based and roles. I'm using in my project claim based approch as it gives me fine grained control on what exact actions user can do in client app (example invoice.create). 
The downside of this that your app as it grows in use cases and requires more permissions then it access token can grow as well - there is non-zero time for parsing token in client app so it could influence performance. Role based approch is kind a grouping permissions in folders so maybe in your case access token will not grow as much using this approch. Too big access token can make some trouble in cases where u didn't expect it to happen - like if u send it in query string so i would say smaller access token than better.